# R - how to find max date in R using sqldf

Tags: r, date, timestamp, max

[image: Image of data]

Getting all corresponding rows after group by with max date?

I have csv file as

```
a = read.csv(file = "a.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

My code:

```
b = sqldf("Select psno , Field_description , log_new_value , MAX 
        (inserted_on) from a group by psno having log_new_value = 'Yes'")
```

But it's giving the wrong answer?

Any experts can help me solving this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the `INSERTED_ON` column is a `character` vector rather than some kind of date-time object.

Try converting them as follows first before calculating the maximum:

```
a$INSERTED_ON <- as.POSIXct(a$INSERTED_ON, format=c("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

Comment: but the result of Inserted_on is not coming in date format
it is coming like this 1489984080

Comment: SQLite does not have a datetime type so sqldf uses a heuristic that if the output has the same name as any POSIXct input column then it will convert it to an R POSIXct variable.  Thus if `inserted_on` is POSIXct in the input data frame use `max(inserted_on) as inserted on` in the sql statement.